# Adding header to docx using openxml

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, openxml, docx

I'm trying to add a new header (manually by using openxml code) to docx (office 2010) document which already contains a header (header1.xml).
I tried to do it with openxml by adding a file named myheader.xml with only one paragraph.
When opening the document at word, the content of header1 is presented in different position (2 lines lower) than it was before.

When I deleted the paragraph, (only `<w:hdr> </w:hdr>` with the relevant name spaces) the content of header1 was still presented in a different potion ( **only** 1 line lower)

Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: So you're trying to read in an existing XML file from disk that contains the right OpenXML markup and add that to a new section in your Word 2010 document, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out this thread here: [Add Header and Footer to an existing empty word document with OpenXML SDK 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672991/add-header-and-footer-to-an-existing-empty-word-document-with-openxml-sdk-2-0/11835692#11835692)

I think it will this solve this problem as, its a little more involed that just adding a paragraph, but not much.