# Add Header and Footer to an existing empty word document with OpenXML SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, header, ms-word, footer, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to add a Header and Footer to an empty word document.

I use this code to add Header part in word/document.xml when change docx to zip.

```
        ApplyHeader(doc);


      public static void ApplyHeader(WordprocessingDocument doc)
      {
            // Get the main document part.
            MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

            // Delete the existing header parts.
            mainDocPart.DeleteParts(mainDocPart.HeaderParts);

            // Create a new header part and get its relationship id.
            HeaderPart newHeaderPart = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
            string rId = mainDocPart.GetIdOfPart(newHeaderPart);

            // Call the GeneratePageHeaderPart helper method, passing in
            // the header text, to create the header markup and then save
            // that markup to the header part.
            GeneratePageHeaderPart("Test1").Save(newHeaderPart);

            // Loop through all section properties in the document
            // which is where header references are defined.
            foreach (SectionProperties sectProperties in
              mainDocPart.Document.Descendants<SectionProperties>())
            {
                //  Delete any existing references to headers.
                foreach (HeaderReference headerReference in
                  sectProperties.Descendants<HeaderReference>())
                    sectProperties.RemoveChild(headerReference);

                //  Create a new header reference that points to the new
                // header part and add it to the section properties.
                HeaderReference newHeaderReference =
                  new HeaderReference() { Id = rId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First };
                sectProperties.Append(newHeaderReference);
            }

            //  Save the changes to the main document part.
            mainDocPart.Document.Save();
        }

    private static Header GeneratePageHeaderPart(string HeaderText)
    {
        var element =
          new Header(
            new Paragraph(
              new ParagraphProperties(
                new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header1" }),
              new Run(
                new Text(HeaderText))
            )
          );

        return element;
    }
```

This code works but there's no header relationship created in word/_rels/document.xml.rels.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings" Target="webSettings.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Target="settings.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Target="fontTable.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

And no more content type header in [Content_Types].xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/word/webSettings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml"/>
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

Nevertheless, header.xml was created in word/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><w:hdr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Header1" /></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>Test1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:hdr>
```

And my word/document.xml to show that my header is added.

```
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="003310CE" w:rsidSect="00D928B6">
<w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
<w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
<w:cols w:space="708" /><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
<w:headerReference w:type="first" r:id="Recfa318e6a7c44ff" />
</w:sectPr>
```

So my question is how to add header and footer correctly ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://www.psp-it.co.uk/blogs/open-xml-usage-part-three/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the solution by myself.

In fact, adding a header or a footer in a docx with OpenXml involves that :

Document has to exist.

Saving and closing document before adding a header or a footer does not work.

```
WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);
<operations on docx>
document.Save();
document.Close();
ChangeHeader(document);
```

You have to re-open a second time your docx to create a new instanciation of the document.

Correct solution will be (with James Wood solution):

```
WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);
<operations on docx>
document.Save();
document.Close();
ChangeHeader(path);

    public static void ChangeHeader(String documentPath)
    {
        // Replace header in target document with header of source document.
        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
        {
            // Get the main document part
            MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

            // Delete the existing header and footer parts
            mainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(mainDocumentPart.HeaderParts);
            mainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(mainDocumentPart.FooterParts);

            // Create a new header and footer part
            HeaderPart headerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
            FooterPart footerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();

            // Get Id of the headerPart and footer parts
            string headerPartId = mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
            string footerPartId = mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart);

            GenerateHeaderPartContent(headerPart);

            GenerateFooterPartContent(footerPart);

            // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id
            IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sections = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();

            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                // Delete existing references to headers and footers
                section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
                section.RemoveAllChildren<FooterReference>();

                // Create the new header and footer reference node
                section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId });
                section.PrependChild<FooterReference>(new FooterReference() { Id = footerPartId });
            }
        }
    }


public static void GenerateHeaderPartContent(HeaderPart part)
        {
            Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Header";

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);

            header1.Append(paragraph1);

            part.Header = header1;
        }

        public static void GenerateFooterPartContent(FooterPart part)
        {
            Footer footer1 = new Footer() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" };

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Footer";

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);

            footer1.Append(paragraph1);

            part.Footer = footer1;
        }
```

Answer (score 37):

I'm quite sure what is wrong with your code, I suspect its the way you are changing the references.

In any case I have a working example which you should hopefully guide you.

I've based mine from examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc546917.aspx

I used the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool to Generate the Header and Footer parts. I first create a document with my desired layout then open it with the tool, it generates the XML or Code. You can get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

The only caveat to this is that it assumes the document already some content in the body, a single letter will do. I'm not sure if this can be avoided, I tried opening an empty document in the Productivity Tool and it suffers from the same error - "Cannot open the file: Archive file cannot be size 0". In my sample it will fail on `WordprocessingDocument.Open`.

Maybe in the case of an empty document you have to create a body first. In any case I suspect the main aim of this question is to add a header and footer so I feel this is a valid answer.

If you want I can provide the actual cs/project files.

Hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace HeaderFooterDocX
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChangeHeader(@"C:\Users\James\Desktop\Document.docx");
        }

        static void ChangeHeader(String documentPath)
        {
            // Replace header in target document with header of source document.
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
            {
                // Get the main document part
                MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

                // Delete the existing header and footer parts
                mainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(mainDocumentPart.HeaderParts);
                mainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(mainDocumentPart.FooterParts);

                // Create a new header and footer part
                HeaderPart headerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
                FooterPart footerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();

                // Get Id of the headerPart and footer parts
                string headerPartId = mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
                string footerPartId = mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart);

                GenerateHeaderPartContent(headerPart);

                GenerateFooterPartContent(footerPart);

                // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id
                IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sections = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();

                foreach (var section in sections)
                {
                    // Delete existing references to headers and footers
                    section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
                    section.RemoveAllChildren<FooterReference>();

                    // Create the new header and footer reference node
                    section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId });
                    section.PrependChild<FooterReference>(new FooterReference() { Id = footerPartId });
                }
            }
        }

        static void GenerateHeaderPartContent(HeaderPart part)
        {
            Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Header";

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);

            header1.Append(paragraph1);

            part.Header = header1;
        }

        static void GenerateFooterPartContent(FooterPart part)
        {
            Footer footer1 = new Footer() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
            footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" };

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Footer";

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);

            footer1.Append(paragraph1);

            part.Footer = footer1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Do you have similar code for Excel Spreadsheet? Or if you could give me direction in which to search? Really cannot find anything about changing header/footer by OpenXML in C#.

Answer (score 17):

this code worked for me. Take into consideration:

1. header's relationship Id is "r97" in my example. Perhaps you would like to decide a unique rId on your own
2. same for footer's relationshipId ("r98")
3. Both header and footer have a hardcoded paragraph with some text.
4. I am assuming a document already exists

   ```
               using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destination, true))
               {
                   var mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                   if (doc == null) {
                       mainDocPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                   }

                   if (mainDocPart.Document == null)
                   {
                       mainDocPart.Document = new Document();
                   }

                   ApplyHeader(doc);

                   ApplyFooter(doc);
               }
   ```

ApplyHeader method:

```
public static void ApplyHeader(WordprocessingDocument doc)
      {
          // Get the main document part.
          MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

          HeaderPart headerPart1 = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("r97");



            Header header1 = new Header();

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){  };



            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Header stuff";

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(run1);


            header1.Append(paragraph1);

            headerPart1.Header = header1;



            SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (sectionProperties1 == null)
            {
                sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { };
                mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);
            }
            HeaderReference headerReference1 = new HeaderReference() { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "r97" };


            sectionProperties1.InsertAt(headerReference1,0);

        }
```

ApplyFooter method:

```
public static void ApplyFooter(WordprocessingDocument doc)
      {
          // Get the main document part.
          MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

          FooterPart footerPart1 = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("r98");



          Footer footer1 = new Footer();

          Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { };



          Run run1 = new Run();
          Text text1 = new Text();
          text1.Text = "Footer stuff";

          run1.Append(text1);

          paragraph1.Append(run1);


          footer1.Append(paragraph1);

          footerPart1.Footer = footer1;



          SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
          if (sectionProperties1 == null)
          {
              sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { };
              mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);
          }
          FooterReference footerReference1 = new FooterReference() { Type = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.HeaderFooterValues.Default,  Id = "r98" };


          sectionProperties1.InsertAt(footerReference1, 0);

      }
```

Enjoy,

Comment: how can i insert html string like "<b>Header Stuff</b>" in the header and footer?

Comment: I like this code because it is much simpler than the other answers, the others have a bunch of unnecessary stuff.  But you don't actually have to assign your own relationshipId, you can get that from MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(HeaderPart).