# FeedData into a FooterPart

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

I've created a word document docx and am now in the process of "reverse engineering" it with the OpenXml productivity tool.  I'm using `.FeedData()` to feed the styles, theme etc. into the document, which I'm saving as .xml files from the reflection - and all was going well, until I came to the footer.

Here's what I'm doing for the styles (this works perfectly fine):

```
StyleDefinitionsPart styleDefinitionsPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("styles.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    styleDefinitionsPart.FeedData(fs);
}
```

Looking at my document, everything is there - now I reflect on the footer part, save the xml to footer.xml and add the part like this:

```
FooterPart footerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("footer.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    footerPart.FeedData(fs);
}
```

Everything else looks fine, I can see the part in my document, but the footer just isn't appearing ON the document, what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to tell the document which footer part to use or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It seems there has to be some content in the body before you can add a footer and header to it, then you need to add a reference to them for each section like this:

```
foreach (var section in mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<WP.SectionProperties>())
{
    section.PrependChild<WP.HeaderReference>(new WP.HeaderReference() { Id = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart) });
    section.PrependChild<WP.FooterReference>(new WP.FooterReference() { Id = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart) });
}
```

Remember to add your header and footer last, so there is content in the document.

HUGE thanks to this answer: [Add Header and Footer to an existing empty word document with OpenXML SDK 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672991/add-header-and-footer-to-an-existing-empty-word-document-with-openxml-sdk-2-0/11835692#11835692)