# Create a header in Word with OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, openxml

I'm trying to create a simple header in Word using OpenXML SDK, but apparently it's not as easy as i thought. I tried several ways: using HeaderPart, SectionProperties and HeaderReference but none of them give the result i'm looking for. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I included some code snippets i tried:

```
using (var package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(writeStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)){
    var mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document();

    var headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
    var header = new Header(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Header Test"))));

    header.Save(headerPart);
}
```

&

```
using (var package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(writeStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)){
    var mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document();

    var headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
    var header = new Header(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Header Test"))));

    headerPart.Header = header;
}
```

&

```
using (var package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(writeStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)){
    var mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document();

    var headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("header1");
    var header = new Header(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Header Test"))));
    header.Save(headerPart);

    var body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
    body.AppendChild(new HeaderReference { Type = HeaderFooterValues.First, Id = "header1" });
}
```

Comment: Can you create a sample Word document of what you are looking for with your header?  If you post the document, we can help provide code to generate the header.

Comment: There are some good examples to add headers to Word documents at stack overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11835692/819019) and above.